# How to get access token using java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I need to get access token using java spring boot application.
I'm able to generate token using postman (As shown in attached file). 
Same I want to achieve it using java spring boot code. I have googled but I didn't get proper answer.[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: See if this helps you understanding what to do.

https://pattern-match.com/blog/2018/10/17/springboot2-with-oauth2-integration/

Comment: Where do we find the attached file?

Comment: @Ahmed Tawila  I have created using postman

Comment: The question does not show enough information to be able to help

Comment: @AhmedTawila using POSTMAN i can generate the token(as shown in the pic). I want to get the same token using spring boot application

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use JWT with Spring Boot? You can store information in this token and see who has the grant. :)